# Overlapping columns in Kivy GUI, grid layout

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have been working on Kivy making a GUI, with a grid layout, and my problem is that the columns of the grid layout are overlapping.

This is only the Kivy part:

```
<SignupScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20

        canvas:
            Rectangle: 
                source: 'images/background.jpg'
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1,0.25

            Label:
                text: 'Vigilant Dollop'
                font_size: '15sp'
                size_hint: 1, 0.20 


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size_hint: 1, 0.1

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Sign Up'
                    font_size: '15sp'
                    on_release: root.manager.current = 'signup'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Login'
                    font_size: '15sp'
                    on_release: root.manager.current = 'login'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Recover'
                    font_size: '15sp'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Reset'
                    font_size: '15sp'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1,0.75

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, 0.1    
                ProgressBar:
                    id: bar
                    max: 1300
                    value:0
            ScrollView:
                size_hint: (1, 1)
                pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                do_scroll_x:False

                GridLayout: 
                    id: layout
                    cols:3
                    spacing:20
                    height: self.minimum_height        
                    size_hint_y:  None
                    Label:
                    TextInput:
                        id: 1
                        hint_text: 'User Name'
                        multiline: False
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                        cursor_color: 0,0,0,1
                        on_text: root.val_change()  
                        write_tab: False
                    Label:
                    Label:
                    TextInput:
                        id: 2
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                        cursor_color: 0,0,0,1
                        focus:True
                        hint_text: "Password"
                        password: True
                        multiline: False     
                        allow_copy: False
                        on_text: root.pass_work()
                        write_tab: False
                    Label:
                        id: MSG
                        text: " "
                    Label:
                    TextInput:
                        id: 3
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                        cursor_color: 0,0,0,1
                        focus:True
                        hint_text: "Confirm Password"
                        password: True
                        multiline: False     
                        allow_copy: False
                        on_text: root.conf_work()
                        write_tab: False
                    Label:
                        id: MSG2
                        text: " "
                    Label:
                    TextInput:
                        id: 4
                        focus: True
                        hint_text: 'E-Mail'
                        multiline: False
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                        cursor_color: 0,0,0,1
                        on_text: root.val_change()
                        write_tab: False
                    Label:
                        id: MSG3
                        text: " "
                    Label:    
                    TextInput:
                        id: 5
                        focus:True
                        hint_text: 'Contact No.' 
                        height:400
                        multiline: False
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                        cursor_color: 0,0,0,1
                        on_text: root.val_change()
                        write_tab: False
                    Label:
                    Label:
                    TextInput:
                        id: 6
                        hint_text: 'D.O.B.'
                        multiline: False
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                        cursor_color: 0,0,0,1
                        on_text: root.val_change()
                        write_tab: False
                    Label:
                    Label:
                    TextInput:
                        id: 10
                        hint_text: 'SSN'
                        multiline: False
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                        cursor_color: 0,0,0,1
                        on_text: root.val_change()
                        write_tab: False
                    Label:
                    Label:
                    TextInput:
                        id: 11
                        hint_text: 'SSN Type'
                        multiline: False
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                        cursor_color: 0,0,0,1
                        on_text: root.val_change()
                        write_tab: False
                    Label:
                    Label:
                    Spinner:
                        background_color: 255,255,255,1
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                        text: "Security Question"
                        values: "Work", "Home", "Mobile", "Skype"
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                    Label:
                    Label:
                    TextInput:
                        id: 12
                        hint_text: 'Answer'
                        multiline: False
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                        cursor_color: 0,0,0,1
                        on_text: root.val_change()
                        write_tab: False
                    Label:
                    Label:
                    Spinner:
                        background_color: 255,255,255,1
                        color: 0,0,0,1
                        text: "Security Question"
                        values: "Work", "Home", "Mobile", "Skype"
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                    Label:
                    Label:
                    TextInput:
                        id: 13
                        hint_text: 'Answer'
                        multiline: False
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size: 350,40
                        cursor_color: 0,0,0,1
                        on_text: root.val_change()  
                        write_tab: False  
                    Label:
                    Button:
                        text: 'Submit'
                        size_hint: None, None
                        size_hint: 0.5,None


<LoginScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20

        canvas:
            Rectangle: 
                source: 'images/background.jpg'
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1,0.25

            Label:
                text: 'Vigilant Dollop'
                font_size: '15sp'
                size_hint: 1, 0.20 


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size_hint: 1, 0.1

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Sign Up'
                    font_size: '15sp'
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'signup'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Login'
                    font_size: '15sp'
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'login'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Recover'
                    font_size: '15sp'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Reset'
                    font_size: '15sp'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1,0.75

            Button: 
                text: 'Page'
```

Please suggest what I should do. What should I do to keep the columns from overlapping?

Comment: This is only the Kivy part

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing overlaping in a working version of Kivy. To debug layouts run a file like this:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<kv lang here>
''')
class SignupScreen(BoxLayout): pass
runTouchApp(SignupScreen())
```

and/or just run it with:

```
python file.py -m inspector
```

which will give you an access to the `Inspector` module. Then with clicking you can see what is where e.g. like here:

[image]

where you can see that you have 3 columns and the items are put on their place correctly. You probably can't see it clearly because there's no text in those `Label`s you use. Or there's a single `Label` missing before the `Button` at the end (if you talk about the "misaligned" button).